# Typescript: Type can be either/or

Tags: typescript

I have the following interface:

```
export interface Channel {
  version: string;

  render<T extends Record<string, unknown>>(payload: Payload, options?: T): Promise<Response>;
  render<T extends Record<string, unknown>>(context: IContext, options?: T): Promise<string>;
}
```

there are two types of Channels (web or nonWeb) that can be rendered. If I try to render one type of channel like this:

```
export interface web extends Channel {
  render(payload: Payload, options?: IWebChannelOptions): Promise<Response>;
}
```

I get `Interface 'web' incorrectly extends interface 'Channel'` because it's incompatible with the other type. The same happens when I try to call the nonWeb channel. What is the best way to resolve this?

Comment: please provide reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your error is not just because your implementation wouldn't work for both Payload and IContext in the first argument, but also because you are restricting T beyond what the interface allows.

Channel's interface definition is a contract: You are promising that regardless of its implementing class, *every* Channel can be called with *the caller's choice* of `render(Payload, T?)` and `render(IContext, T)` *for the caller's choice of `T`*. That's what would allow you to interact with Channel as an interface without knowing its exact implementation. The fact that the name is the same is irrelevant to this contract: If Channel's methods were named `a` and `b`, you couldn't get away with only implementing `a` and leaving `b`, or it would break the contract that every conforming `Channel`s can be called both ways.

The most obvious answer is to **remove `render` from the Channel definition**, then test which implementation you have before interacting with it.

That invites the question: Setting aside `version`, if Channel's two implementations don't share any useful method signatures, is there any reason for Channel to exist as an interface rather than `type Channel = Web | NonWeb`? What could you possibly pass `render` without figuring out whether the channel is web or nonWeb? This isn't as much of a downside in TypeScript as it might be if you're coming from a language like Java: If both Web and NonWeb declared `version: string`, TypeScript's [structural typing system](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) would correctly infer that `Web | NonWeb` contains a `version: string` without you having to declare it.

If you're sure you want an array of `Channel`, you can check to TypeScript's satisfaction either by checking `instanceof web` or `instanceof nonWeb`, by using a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), or by writing your own custom [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) available on Channel (`isWeb(): this is web`) that you call instead of `instanceof`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's an option, but you could make `Channel` completely generic and then use type parameters in `Web`, maybe something like this?

```
export interface Channel<Input = unknown, Output = unknown> {
  version: string;
  render(context: Input, options?: Record<string, unknown>): Promise<Output>;
}

type TestOpts = { a: number };

export interface Web extends Channel<string, string> {
  render(payload: string, options?: TestOpts): Promise<string>;
}
```